# To construct domain objects I need to join a table to itself and transpose the results. Can I get Entity Framework to do this for me?

Tags: entity-framework, teradata

My current project involves a domain concept called an SOQ. Conceptually, an SOQ can be described as having the following attributes:

- LocationType
- LocationID
- ProductNumber
- VendorNumber
- Date
- Qty
- Status

How an SOQ is represented in the database is a completely different story.

## The short version

Getting an SOQ object that looks like the above description involves joining a table to itself and transposing some column data into row data.

My current situation is that I'm using a straight table-to-object mapping in Entity Framework, and have implemented the self-join and transposition "after the fact", with the results of this transformation being represented in a second class.

The situation I'd like to be in is that querying the ObjectContext will simply return a nice domain object that hides the convoluted database representation. This object will need to be able to be read and persist updates to the database. I will never be creating or deleting these objects.

Is this possible?

## The long version

- An SOQ may exist in one of two database tables, fardaily or farweekly.
- Both tables have a compound key consisting of LocationType, LocationId, ProductNumber, VendorNumber and **FieldType** columns.
- Both tables also have numerous columns named like DateNN:

  - FarDaily has columns Day01..Day28,
  - FarWeekly has columns Week01..Week65.
- The date columns are of type Decimal
- The meaning of the value of the DateNN columns of a given row is determined by the value of that row's FieldType column.

  - Fieldtype 52 means the DateNN columns contain Qty values
  - Fieldtype 54 means Status values.

For example:

```
LocationType  LocationID  ProductNumber ... FieldType  Day01  Day02 ...
100           S           999               52         5      2
100           S           999               54         0      1
```

This (truncated) example shows two SOQs - one for Day01 and one for Day02.

- The Day01 SOQ has a qty of 5, and a status of 0.
- The Day02 SOQ has a qty of 2 and a status of 1.

A more sensible representation would be one where one row (or object) represented one SOQ:

```
LocationType  LocationID  ProductNumber ... FieldType  Day  Qty  Status
100           S           999               52         1      5  0
100           S           999               54         2      2  1
```

As I mentioned above, I'm currently creating such objects myself. But I'm wondering if it's possible to get Entity Framework to do this for me?

Comment: So in fact you want to define a class with properties that each get populated by a SELECT statement? If so, EF can't do this. I think NHibernate can (formula property), but only reading, not updating.